# Question for starting django web (beginner))

Tags: html, django

I have experienced problem in creating my own page on django. I follow the tutorial but get the different results. The error is page not found and Using the URLconf defined in djangonautic.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
about/
^$

The empty path didn’t match any of these.It would be appreciate if someone can help me:

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from. import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^about/$', views.about),
    path(r'^$', views.homepage),
    path(r'^$', views.index),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('my name is Jacky')


def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse('welcome home')


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world I am the king")
```

The web page will be display normally, no 404 is found

Answer (score 0):

First, the import in urls.py (in your app directory) should be,

```
from . import views
```

Secondly, you do not really need to specify a URL path for the admin page, so better to get rid of that from your urls.py file as that is handled by django in the urls.py file in the appname/url.py file.

Third, ensure that in your projectname/urls.py file, you have included the path to your urls.py file in appname/urls.py file.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('inventory.urls')),
]
```